# Why the deref() operation of String type returns reference of str, but Asterisk operator returns str?

Tags: rust

I am a new learner of Rust, I see the `*` operator can be overloaded by `Deref` trait. The `std::string::String` type have `Deref` trait implemented, which returns `&str` type. However when I do the following test, the compiler tells me the type of `s2` is `str`, with an error message "size for values of type `str` cannot be known at compilation time". So the code cannot be compiled. But the question is why `s2` is `str`? Shouldn't it be the same type as `s1`?

```rust
let owned = "test".to_string(); // owned type is String
let s1 = owned.deref(); // s1 type is &str
let s2 = *owned; // s2 type is str
```

Answer (score 5):

`Deref` is a bit of a special trait in Rust, and the rules can be found in the [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html). There are some other places where `Deref` coercion occurs, but since you asked about unary `*`, the first rule on that page is relevant to you.

> If `T` implements `Deref<Target = U>`, and `x` is a value of type `T`, then:
>
> - In immutable contexts, `*x` (where `T` is neither a reference nor a raw pointer) is equivalent to `*Deref::deref(&x)`.

So after `Deref::deref` is called, Rust tries the unary `*` again. This *can* invoke `Deref` on some other type, as seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519997/what-are-rusts-exact-auto-dereferencing-rules). This is also the same way C++'s overloadable `->` operator works. It does some sort of (user-defined) coercion and then tries to dereference again, which may recursively call `->` on something else.

So this

```
let s2 = *owned;
```

is equivalent to

```
let s2 = *owned.deref();
```

And has type `str`. `str` is not a `Sized` type and hence can't be stored in a variable, which causes your error.

As for *why* Rust does this, the `Deref` trait is defined to take a reference and return a reference. This makes sense, since it's coercing some sort of reference behind the scenes, not actually creating data. Nine times out of ten, `Deref` simply returns a reference to some inner data on the outer structure (`Box` being a prime example of this).

On the other hand, when you as the programmer write `*`, you clearly don't want a reference. After all, you just went out of your way to *dereference* the data. So the `*` allows deref-coercion through the `Deref` trait but then still tries to take ownership of (or copy, if applicable) the data after coercion is finished.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take another look at the relationship between `Deref` and the dereference operator:

```
let owned = "test".to_string(); // owned type is String
let s1 = owned.deref();  // type of s1 is &str
let s2 = &*owned;   // type of s2 is also &str
//let s3 = *owned;  // if this compiled, type of s3 would be str
```

Note how `*x` expands to `*x.deref()`, not to `x.deref()` itself. This you can think of `deref()` as a "pre-processing" step before applying the actual dereference operator. This is why the above example needed `&*owned`, and why `*owned` doesn't compile, despite `owned.deref()` compiling just fine.